# uniquify an array/list with a tolerance in python (uniquetol equivalent)

Tags: python, numpy, unique

I want to find the unique elements of an array in a certain range of tolerance

For instance, for an array/list

```
[1.1 , 1.3 , 1.9 , 2.0 , 2.5 , 2.9]
```

Function will return

```
[1.1 , 1.9 , 2.5 , 2.9]
```

If the tolerance is `0.3`

at bit like the MATLAB function 
[http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uniquetol.html](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uniquetol.html)
(but this function uses a relative tolerance, an absolute one can be sufficient)
What is the pythonic way to implement it ? (`numpy` is privilegied)

Comment: If the input is `[ 1.1,  1.3,  1.5,  2. ,  2.1,  2.5,  2.9]`, what must be the output for that tolerance of `0.3`?

Comment: And also, would be the input be always sorted?

Answer (score 8):

With `A` as the input array and `tol` as the tolerance value, we could have a vectorized approach with [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html), like so -

```
A[~(np.triu(np.abs(A[:,None] - A) <= tol,1)).any(0)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [20]: A = np.array([2.1,  1.3 , 1.9 , 1.1 , 2.0 , 2.5 , 2.9])

In [21]: tol = 0.3

In [22]: A[~(np.triu(np.abs(A[:,None] - A) <= tol,1)).any(0)]
Out[22]: array([ 2.1,  1.3,  2.5,  2.9])
```

Notice `1.9` being gone because we had `2.1` within the tolerance of `0.3`. Then, `1.1` gone for `1.3` and `2.0` for `2.1`.

Please note that this would create a unique array with "chained-closeness" check. As an example :

```
In [91]: A = np.array([ 1.1,  1.3,  1.5,  2. ,  2.1,  2.2, 2.35, 2.5,  2.9])

In [92]: A[~(np.triu(np.abs(A[:,None] - A) <= tol,1)).any(0)]
Out[92]: array([ 1.1,  2. ,  2.9])
```

Thus, `1.3` is gone because of `1.1` and `1.5` is gone because of `1.3`.

Answer (score 2):

In pure Python 2, I wrote the following:

```
a = [1.1, 1.3, 1.9, 2.0, 2.5, 2.9]                                              

# Per http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uniquetol.html                                                                                    
tol = max(map(lambda x: abs(x), a)) * 0.3                                       

a.sort()                                                                        

results = [a.pop(0), ]                                                          

for i in a:
    # Skip items within tolerance.                                                                     
    if abs(results[-1] - i) <= tol:                                             
        continue                                                                
    results.append(i)                                                           

print a                                                                         
print results
```

Which results in

```
[1.3, 1.9, 2.0, 2.5, 2.9]
[1.1, 2.0, 2.9]
```

Which is what the spec seems to agree with, but isn't consistent with your example.

If I just set the tolerance to `0.3` instead of `max(map(lambda x: abs(x), a)) * 0.3`, I get:

```
[1.3, 1.9, 2.0, 2.5, 2.9]
[1.1, 1.9, 2.5, 2.9]
```

...which is consistent with your example.