# How to check if given four tuple points form a square, rectangle, parallelogram or rhombus in python?

Tags: python

There are four points as a tuple; `p1 = (2, 2), p2 = (2, 6), p3 = (6, 6) and p4 = (6, 2)`. I want these four tuple points to pass in 4 different type of functions: isSquare(p1, p2, p3, p4), isRectangle(p1, p2, p3, p4), isParallelogram(p1, p2, p3, p4) and isRhombus(p1, p2, p3, p4) to check if its a square, rectangle, parallelogram or rhombus.

Comment: is ```(2, 6)``` supposed to be in there twice?

Comment: No no it was a mistake, its p4 = (6, 2)

Comment: You can use this [formula](https://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Distance-Between-Two-Points#:~:text=How%20to%20Find%20Distance%20between%20Two%20Points%201,the%20final%20step%20in%20the%20equation.%20See%20More.) To check the length of lines made by these points and check the [property of quadrilateral](https://e-gmat.com/blogs/quadrilateral-properties-formulas-rectangle-square-parallelogram-rhombus-trapezium-trapezoid/)

Answer (score 0):

Edit attempt 2:
Instead calculate vectors between points and find the number of unique vectors and the angles between vectors that meet at the same point to determine which shape of the four required if any it is (Note this method requires points to be ordered in the order they are connected):

```
import numpy as np

def quadrilateral2(*args):
    if len(args) != 4:
        return 'Not a quadrilateral'
    args = np.array(args)
    vectors = np.array([args[i-1]-j for i, j in enumerate(args)])
    unique_vectors = np.unique(np.round(np.abs(vectors), 6), axis=0) #Round to avoid numerical errors: can change the number of digits to round to
    if len(unique_vectors) != 2:
        return 'Not a square, rectangle, rhombus or parallelogram'
    norms = [np.linalg.norm(i) for i in vectors]
    norm_vectors = [i/j for i, j in zip(vectors, norms)]
    unique_norms = set(round(i, 6) for i in norms) # Again, round for numerical errors
    angles = [np.arccos(np.dot(norm_vectors[i-1], j)) for i, j in enumerate(norm_vectors)]

    if all(i == np.pi/2 for i in angles):
        if len(unique_norms) == 1:
            return 'Square'
        if len(unique_norms) == 2:
            return 'Rectangle'
    
    elif len(set(round(i, 6) for i in angles)) == 2: #Again, round for numerical errors
        if len(unique_norms) == 1:
            return 'Rhombus'
        if len(unique_norms) == 2:
            return 'Parallelogram'
    else:
        return 'Not a square, rectangle, rhombus or parallelogram'
```

Test with previous tests and those given as comments:

```
square = [(2, 2), (2, 4), (4,4), (4, 2)]
rectangle = [(2, 2), (2,8), (4, 8), (4, 2)]
rhombus = [(0, 0), (np.sqrt(8), 0), (2+np.sqrt(8), 2), (2, 2)]
parallelogram = [(2,2), (5, 2), (6,4), (3,4)]
print(quadrilateral2(*square))
print(quadrilateral2(*rectangle))
print(quadrilateral2(*rhombus))
print(quadrilateral2(*parallelogram))
print(quadrilateral2(*[[2, -3], [6, 5], [-2, 1], [-6, -7]]))
print(quadrilateral2(*[(0, 0), (0, -5), (3,2.5), (3, -2.5)]))
print(quadrilateral2(*[(0, 2), (0, -2), (-1,0), (1, 0)]))
```

Output:

```
Square
Rectangle
Rhombus
Parallelogram
Rhombus
Not a square, rectangle, rhombus or parallelogram
Not a square, rectangle, rhombus or parallelogram
```

Disclaimer: Doesn't work for any input, but I think it works if the input is guaranteed to be a square, rectangle, parallelogram or rhombus.
Ok, I think this works but I haven't tested it much. Essentially, you need to compute the unique distances and unique angles between all the given points and then use your knowledge of the desired shapes to decide from these distances and angles which shape if any it is:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np


def quadrilateral(*args):
    tol = 1e-4
    if not len(args) == 4:
        return 'Not a quadrilateral'
    #Calculate all permutations of the coordinates
    permutations = np.array(list(itertools.permutations(args, r=2)))
    #Calculate all distances
    distances = np.array(list(np.sqrt(sum((i[0]-i[1])**2)) for i in permutations))
    #Choose unique distances within a tolerance tol
    distances = distances[~(np.triu(np.abs(distances[:,None] - distances) <= tol,1)).any(0)]
    #Calculate all absolute angles
    angles = np.array(list(abs(np.arctan2(*(i[0]-i[1])[::-1])) for i in permutations))
    #Choose unique angles within a tolerance tol
    angles = sorted(angles[~(np.triu(np.abs(angles[:,None] - angles) <= tol,1)).any(0)])
    if len(distances) == 2 and all(np.pi*i/4 == j for i, j in enumerate(angles)):
            return "It's a square"
    elif len(distances) == 3:
        if len(angles) == 5:
            return "It's a rectangle"
        elif len(angles) == 8:
            return "It's a rhombus"
        else:
            return 'Not a square, rectangle, rhombus or parallelogram'
    elif len(distances) == 4 and len(angles) == 8:
        return "It's a parallelogram"
    else:
        return 'Not a square, rectangle, rhombus or parallelogram'
```

Simple test cases:

```
square = [(2, 2), (2, 4), (4,2), (4, 4)]
rectangle = [(2, 2), (4, 2), (2,8), (4, 8)]
rhombus = [(0, 0), (2, 2), (np.sqrt(8), 0), (2+np.sqrt(8), 2)]
parallelogram = [(2,2), (3,4), (5, 2), (6,4)]
print(quadrilateral(*square))
print(quadrilateral(*rectangle))
print(quadrilateral(*rhombus))
print(quadrilateral(*parallelogram))
```

Output:

```
It's a square
It's a rectangle
It's a rhombus
It's a parallelogram
```

Comment: There might be some logic issues. It reports this as a rectangle:  `[(0, 2), (0, -2), (-1,0), (1, 0)]`

Comment: Is there any other way to solve this problem like using oops?

Comment: It also thinks this is a rectangle: `[(0, 0), (0, -5), (3,2.5), (3, -2.5)]`, but it's a dart.

Comment: @Mark as I said, not tested very much but it gives an idea of how to solve the problem. I think that can be fixed by also checking if all I*pi/4 are in the angles as I did for the square

Comment: Actually I*pi/2

Comment: It's working somehow but I didn't understand anything.

Comment: @SachinKumar which bits don't you understand?

Comment: Actually, I am new to python. And it's too overwhelming for me. :(

Comment: @SachinKumar it doesn't actually work as mark points out, but it does for a few cases, I'll try and do a different method based on vectors that should work for all cases. As for understanding the method to find unique values was copied from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37847053/uniquify-an-array-list-with-a-tolerance-in-python-uniquetol-equivalent and was done to avoid rounding errors in the calculations and the other possibly new concepts would be list comprehension / generator expressions which I used to calculate the distances and angles

Comment: OK, no problem. It would be better if you help me in time. Thanks.

Comment: @Nin17 It's not working for the rhombus. Whenever I'm trying to give the rhombus coordinates it's showing a parallelogram.

Comment: @SachinKumar can you give me some example coordinates that don't work

Comment: @Nin17 Sorry, it's saying not a rhombus. And these are the coordinates;  ver = [[2, -3], [6, 5], [-2, 1], [-6, -7]]

Comment: @Nin17 Actually, your code is somehow working for square, rectangle and parallelogram, but not for rhombus.

Comment: @SachinKumar well I guess this is another example of the code not working. I think a better approach would be to compute the vectors between adjacent points (and then the points would have to be in the order they are connected) and then check that the number of pairs of parallel vectors is 2 (which it should be for all of your shapes) and then calculate the angles between two vectors that meet at the same point (```np.dot()```) to determine which shape if any it is

Comment: @Nin17 Can you make some improvements to the code? Because the rest is almost fine.

Comment: @SachinKumar yep I'm working on it

Comment: @SachinKumar I've updated my answer with a new method that works for the given test cases. note that now the points have to be given in the order they are connected in the shape